# How to bundle project config files with parcel

Tags: node.js, bundler, parcel, parceljs

I have created a common utility package which will be used by multiple node applications and for bundling it, I am using [parcel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel) which works fine but except one issue.

The common utility package consists of [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) files, which takes care of loading configuration as per env.

**Issue:**
While using this common utility package in a nodeapp I get the below error, when i try to run the app:

```
Error: loggerConfig config variable not found
at Object.n [as getLoggerConfig] (/Users/pm/Documents/example-service/node_modules/common.utils/dist/index.js:14:1037)
```

So It seems to me, the config files are not bundled along the build files generated.

**Help Needed:**

1. Is there a way we can tell parcel to bundle these config files as well?
2. Please guide me if I am thinking the wrong way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have managed this by preparing a config JSON for multiple env and using it based on the process.env.NODE_ENV.